# algorithmic, Long lines of code being displayed with sporadic spacing

Tags: algorithmic

I'm using LaTeX for the first time, and I'm having trouble showing the pseudocode for an algorithm. Here is what I have:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{RSTM vector push\_back operation}\label{pushback}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{push\_back}{$val$}\Comment{push $val$ onto end of vector}
\State \textit{BEGIN\_TRANSACTION}
\State $sh\_ptr<VectorItem> new\_val \gets new\,\, sh\_ptr<VectorItem>(new VectorItem(val))$
\State $sh\_ptr<VectorItem> desc \gets new\,\, sh\_ptr<VectorItem>(new VectorDesc(L_{desc} -> size + 1))$
\State $mem[size] \gets new\_val$
\State $L_{desc} \gets desc$
\State \textit{END\_TRANSACTION}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I end up with this result:
[image: result]

As you can see on lines 3 and 4, there is a lot of extra spacing going on that I don't want. I've had little luck fixing it without causing other weird things to happen. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines are two long, so you will need a line break, best inserted manually at a suitable place. One basic problem is that you typeset everything in mathmode and misuse the less-than and greater-than operators as angle brackets. I suggest to introduce the following macros.

```
\newcommand\id[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand\param[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\new{\mathit{new}\ }
```

`\id{...}` is for marking identifiers, which are typeset in italics. Note that there is a considerable difference between `$\mathit{different}$` and `$different$`.

[image]

To avoid the latter, use `\mathit` or `\mathrm` or `\mathtt` or ... to typeset names in math mode.

`\param{...}` is intended to mark type parameters and wraps its argument in angle brackets. As a (bad) alternative you can use less-than and greater-than-operators, but you have to remove the spacing of the operators.

```
\newcommand\varparam[1]{{<}#1{>}}
```

Decide yourself whether you prefer `\param{\id{VectorItem}}` or `\varparam{\id{VectorItem}}`.

[image]

Here is my suggestion for how to typeset the algorithms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\newcommand\id[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand\param[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\new{\mathit{new}\ }
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{RSTM vector push\_back operation}\label{pushback}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{push\_back}{$val$}\Comment{push $val$ onto end of vector}
\State \textit{BEGIN\_TRANSACTION}
\State $\id{sh\_ptr}\param{\id{VectorItem}}\id{new\_val} \gets{}$\\
        \hfill$\new\id{sh\_ptr}\param{\id{VectorItem}}(\new\id{VectorItem}(\id{val}))$
\State $\id{sh\_ptr}\param{\id{VectorItem}}\id{desc} \gets{}$\\
        \hfill$\new\id{sh\_ptr}\param{\id{VectorItem}}(\new\id{VectorDesc}(L_{\id{desc}} \rightarrow \id{size} + 1))$
\State $\id{mem}[\id{size}] \gets \id{new\_val}$
\State $L_{\id{desc}} \gets \id{desc}$
\State \textit{END\_TRANSACTION}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines 3 and 4 are too long and are broken across lines. Default is justification, thus the first line is stretched to fit the line width.
Adding `\raggedright` seems to help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{RSTM vector push\_back operation}\label{pushback}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\raggedright
\Procedure{push\_back}{$val$}\Comment{push $val$ onto end of vector}
\State \textit{BEGIN\_TRANSACTION}
\State $sh\_ptr<VectorItem> new\_val \gets new\,\, sh\_ptr<VectorItem>(new VectorItem(val))$
\State $sh\_ptr<VectorItem> desc \gets new\,\, sh\_ptr<VectorItem>(new VectorDesc(L_{desc} -> size + 1))$
\State $mem[size] \gets new\_val$
\State $L_{desc} \gets desc$
\State \textit{END\_TRANSACTION}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Alternatively, `\newline` can be added to break the overlong lines 3 and 4 manually.

Comment: I'd also change references to obviously-textual content using `\text` or something similar (for example, variables like `newVectorItem` using `\text{newVectorItem}`).